# When do spring transaction timeout for default value of -1?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-transactions

This is my bean

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
          <property name="defaultTimeout" value="400" />            
    </bean>
```

Spring JpaTransactionManager default time out is -1.In my case I have overridden  defaultTimeout with 400 sec.So,if I have overridden it then it will time out  after specified defaultTimeout time.

Looking at the code on **DataSourceTransactionManager** class

```
int timeout = determineTimeout(definition);
            if (timeout != -1) {
                txObject.getConnectionHolder().setTimeoutInSeconds(timeout);
            }


public void setTimeoutInSeconds(int seconds) {
        setTimeoutInMillis(seconds * 1000);
        public void setTimeoutInMillis(long millis) {
        this.deadline = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + millis);
    }
}
```

So if timeout value is not equal to -1 then timeout i have specified is multiple by 1000 and that is used for timeout.But,in case i have not overridden timeout value then it will be -1.

**So,when will be timeout occur for default value of -1 .**

**Does it time out when MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Timeout expired exception is thrown?**
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

When the server times out, MySql itself has its own timeouts too. Benchmark few different long running queries in debug mode, if you see same times taken for the exception then that is from the server timeout.

Answer (score 0):

`-1` is a placeholder for NONE. All classes in the [org.springframework.transaction](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/package-summary.html) package use it to signal the NO TIMEOUT has been set, therefore Spring is going to use the default timeout of the underlying transaction system, or none if timeouts are not supported.

You can read this definition in the [TransactionDefinition](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/TransactionDefinition.html#TIMEOUT_DEFAULT) class.